# Why does IIS7 on one server work with my certificate while another has problems?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate, certificate

In the setup I describe, we have two servers, Alpha and Bravo.

Alpha is a server that has been around for years.  It is a Windows 2008 server running IIS7.  In order to log in to any application on Alpha, a user presents a smart-card certificate to the server.

Our development group wanted to have a "test" server that we could experiment with, and so our network support team set up a new server, Bravo.  Bravo was meant to have the same functionality as Alpha, but the development group would have broad access to modify and deploy web applications for testing purposes.

Next, we have two members of our development group: Alice and Bob.  Alice begins working with the new server Bravo as soon as it is set up.  She has no trouble accessing web applications on Bravo with her smart-card.  As far as she can tell, Bravo is an exact clone of Alpha, but with a different name and IP address.

Alice sets up a web application on Bravo and invites Bob to try it out.  Bob has never used Bravo before, but has been assured that it works just like Alpha.  However, when Bob tries to access *any* web application on Bravo, he sees the following error message:

```
HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.
```

Alice and Bob are very frustrated because their workstations are expected to be configured exactly the same, and Alpha and Bravo both use the exact same certificates.

The network support team checks that Alice and Bob have the same settings in IE8 (because that is what our organization must support).  The network support team also tries using Alice's smart-card to log in to Bravo on Bob's workstation.  This doesn't work, thus eliminating Bob's smart-card as the source of the problem.

What could possibly be the reason that Alice and Bob can both log in to Alpha with their smart-cards, but only Alice and log into Bravo with hers?

To repeat, both Alpha and Bravo should be using the exact same certificates.

Comment: What are the client certificate mapping settings on Bravo, and is it configured for one-one mapping?

Comment: @Greg, where do I access the setting that you discuss?

Comment: Web Site > SSL Settings > Client Certificates.  One-one mappings are described here: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/configuring-one-to-one-client-certificate-mappings